# How to hide all the verbose or login tty7 on bootup?

Tags: boot, xorg, login

I'm a newbie in Ubuntu and now there's a problem I tried many ways but still can't make it,so I'm now here asking for help.

What I want to make is a OS that bootup and show Graphic theme(plymouth) and then to graphic terminal , what I mean is ... like Desktop , login tty7 automatically, without any verbose after the theme.

I'm now using a Ubuntu server cause it's the smaller the better,and I write something in ~/.profile and some other files to make a autologin root and auto start 'startx',so,after the plymouth theme , it's in tty1 , it logs into root and startx and goto tty7 automatically , but ,there's some verbose.

I've tried to chmod 000 for utmp,btmp and lastlog in /var/log/ and delete /etc/issue and /etc/update-motd.d , BUT there's still few verbose left.

1. last login - How can I hide it?
2. after the startx it shows :X.Org X server - How to hide it ?
3. If it's impossible or too difficult to hide them , can I login tty7 on bootup , just like Ubuntu Desktop?(I only installed xorg , no other desktop things shall be installed)
4. If possible , how can I hide the verbose when shutdown or reboot? I tried to add clear above exit 0 in rc.local , it doesn't work!

   Thanks very much for anyone who can help!

I hide last login successfully, according to http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-display-clear-last-login-information/

but xorg startup verbose needs to be hidden. Same with shutdown verbose.

I finally make it another way , I mean , hide all the welcome information according to 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1449020  Hope it will be of use to someone like me.

Comment: you may want to research what a display manager is. for reference, the display manager that unity uses by default is lightdm.

Comment: lightdm is about 150M,which is far too big . The basic requirements of the UI satisfied by only xong installed is enough , now it's only the verbose things.

Comment: there are way smaller display managers than lightdm, if that's a problem. see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Manager, which includes some smaller ones

Comment: I tried xdm but get dizzy by ratpoison...I removed it , thanks all the same.